# How to link datasource to a value within another datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'll explain the problem with an example in WinForms and C#:

```
class Foo { List<Bar> Bars { get; } ... }
class Bar { ... }
var foos = new List<Foo>();
```

I start by setting my list of `Foo`s as the datasource for a `ListBox`:

```
var fooListBox = new ListBox();
fooListBox.DataSource = foos;
```

Now I want to have a second `ListBox` whose datasource is always the list of `Bar`s of the *selected* `Foo` (or `null` otherwise). Conceptually:

```
var barListBox = new ListBox();
barListBox.DataSource = fooListBox.SelectedValue.Bars;
```

**Is there a simple solution to this problem?**

I'm currently hooking it up manually like this:

```
barListBox.DataSource = fooListBox.SelectedValue != null ? ((Foo)fooListBox.SelectedValue).Bars : null;
fooListBox.SelectedValueChanged += (s,e) => barListBox.DataSource = fooListBox.SelectedValue != null ? ((Foo)fooListBox.SelectedValue).Bars : null;
```

But I can't help but think I'm overlooking something important.

Comment: The point of the BindingSource is that, especially in your setup, it keeps your two sources of data tied together.  I assume that you are passing to your user control a List<Foo>. If that's the case, there's got to be _some_ control there that is selecting one item in the List<Foo> as the Current item.  As long as you're binding that control to your user control's DataSource, you shouldn't have to even worry about having a SelectedFoo property. So, what control is handling the List<Foo>?

Comment: @BradRem There's not a single List<Foo> anywhere. There's a Game class with *several* lists, such as Objects, Characters, Regions. My user control takes a Game reference and serves as a way to choose *one* entity between *all* of those sources. So in other words I have multiple data sources, but those are encapsulated, so that to the outside the only part that matters is that there's a SelectedEntity property. Then outside I have the ListBox whose datasource should always be bound to a *member* of the currently SelectedEntity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, you can use [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158145.aspx) to keep your objects synchronized.

```
// first binding source that points to your List of Foos
BindingSource bindingSourceFoos = new BindingSource();
bindingSourceFoos.DataSource = foos;

// create a second binding source that references the first's Bars property
BindingSource bindingSourceBars = new BindingSource(bindingSourceFoos, "Bars");

// set DisplayMember to the property in class Foo you wish to display in your listbox
fooListBox.DisplayMember = "FooName"; // my example, replace with actual name
fooListBox.DataSource = bindingSourceFoos;

// again, set DisplayMember to the property in Bar that you want to display in ListBox
barListBox.DisplayMember = "BarInfo"; // my example, replace with actual name
barListBox.DataSource = bindingSourceBars;
```

So, from this point on, when you click on something in the FooListBox, it will automatically change the contents of the BarListBox to that Foo's Bar collection.

Update:

[MSDN - Databinding to a user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233787.aspx)

That link should tell you everything you need to know, but just in case:

Decorate your user control like this:

```
[System.ComponentModel.LookupBindingProperties
  ("DataSource", "DisplayMember", "ValueMember", "LookupMember")]
public partial class FooSelector : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Add these members to your user control:

```
    public object DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return fooListBox.DataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            fooListBox.DataSource = value;
        }
    }

    public string DisplayMember
    {
        get { return fooListBox.DisplayMember; }
        set { fooListBox.DisplayMember = value; }
    }

    public string ValueMember
    {
        get { return fooListBox.ValueMember; }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null) && (value != ""))
                fooListBox.ValueMember = value;
        }
    }

    public string LookupMember
    {
        get
        {
            if (fooListBox.SelectedValue != null)
                return fooListBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            else
                return "";
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null) && (value != ""))
                fooListBox.SelectedValue = value;
        }
    }
```

And then, just like in my original example, you're binding the same way as if you were binding to a normal listbox:

```
// fooSelector1 is your FooSelector user control
fooSelector1.DisplayMember = "Name";
fooSelector1.DataSource = bindingSourceFoos;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I actually noticed the problem right after posting my comment so I deleted it :) I confirm that it works perfectly. Unfortunately I might have over simplified the problem when making the question thinking that it would be easily transferable to my actual scenario. But I'm a bit stuck. I'll update my question in a bit to reflect the problem.

Comment: @DavidGouveia, I've added a link. Code example to follow if you need more help.

Comment: Sorry but I'm still having problems implementing it. :( In your example it was easy to implement the LookupBindingProperties attribute because the user control had a list box inside of it. So implementing the attribute was just  matter of delegating to the inner list. I don't have a list box inside my user control - the implementation details don't really matter (basically it's a complex control with multiple tabs, multiple data sources and multiple list boxes). But to the outside the only thing I care about is the current value and changes of that single property (SelectedFoo in my example).

Comment: The question was becoming too contrived, so I've cleaned it up and awarded you the answer to the original question. I'll rethink a way to explain the problem and post as a separate question. Thank you for your help.